# "I can't believe"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a problem with the following sentence:

> I can’t believe, sometimes the TV program creators treat the audience like they are stupid.

Something is wrong with it, but I can't find the solution (My teacher told me to correct it, but I can't. (usage of this site is accepted by him)

Comment: @User40475 Please do not write the answer in comments. If you know the answer, please write it in the space for answers.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Got it. :)

Comment: Dear Eddie, Thanks a lot for your comprehensive solution. I loved it.

Answer (score 1):

> I can’t believe, sometimes the TV program creators treat the audience like they are stupid .

Try reading the sentence aloud to yourself, and I'm sure you would hardly like it. Commas denote pauses and yours introduces an unnecessary pause— a hiccup in what otherwise should be a freely-flowing sentence. That, in my opinion, is the error in your sentence.

Furthermore, it is advisable to use *that* after *believe* if the writing is intended to be formal. And of course unless you're referring to some particular *"TV program anchors"* you'd better drop that definite article.

Keeping in mind all this, you could rephrase your sentence thus:

> I can’t believe that sometimes [the] TV program creators treat the audience like they are stupid .

Comment: This is one possible answer.  Another is that the OP missed out the word "it".  (In some languages you can say "I can't believe" without an object, just on its own.)  In that case, perhaps the intention was to say: "I can't believe it; sometimes the TV program creators treat the audience like they are stupid."

Comment: That's right, @rjpond.